# How to get data from a specific row in using a ResultSet object?

Tags: java, sql, row, resultset

I have a `ResultSet` object which returns n* number of rows, and so now I want to get a specific row defined by me from that n number of records. If I can get last row only, that would do.

```
while(rs.next()){
  if(rs.last()){   
    double tempTotal = rs.getDouble("openingBalance");      
  }
}
```

Comment: no research effort shown, have a look at the api doc. You can get a specific row using #absolute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`ResultSet.absolute(int row)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#absolute%28int%29) method to select the row you want.

You can also iterate through the ResultSet like this:

```
rs.next();
while(!rs.isAfterLast()){
  rs.getDouble("openingBalance");
  rs.next();
}
```

The reason your iteration loop would not work was because when you call the rs.last() method, it sets the ResultSet's row to the last row.

If the only row you want to get is the last row, then all you need to do is:

```
rs.last();
rs.getDouble("openingBalance");
```